# Meta editing-help should mention "paragraph breaks"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, editing

If I don't overlook something obvious [meta.askubuntu.com/editing-help](https://meta.askubuntu.com/editing-help) does not mention **paragraph breaks** at all. Neither

- how they are considered useful instead of wasting space nor
- how one creates them (by pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> twice?).

Should such an item be added?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, paragraph breaks should be included. And they should appear first (or right before *line breaks*, wherever *line breaks* appears).

That way, anyone who considers adding a line break and checks the help to see how, will know how to add a paragraph break too. Paragraph breaks are often unintentionally missing in new users' posts, and it's much more often helpful to add paragraph breaks than line breaks.

Thanks for noticing this!

Comment: Any idea when this will be accomplished? :-))

Comment: @guntbert This would have to be implemented network-wide (and should be!). Maybe search [MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) and if there's no post there for it, make one. That might move things along.